# Hibernate Can't Connect To MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

i have a application deployed at window Server 12,my application use hibernate as ORM.
my problem is that when i restart my Mysql, i can't authenticate anymore without reload the application
there is any solution for this ?? 
thank you

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: the problem is, when i deploy my application it was one sessionFactory created with the application (application scop), and when connexion is closed one time my sessionFactory can't create sessions anymore that way i try to connect if there is a problem i recreate my sessionFactory.
this was an explication for my situation, i hope that will help somebody